# Unity controllable hinge joint on catapult

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My catapult consists of an arm and a base. The arm is connected to the base with a hinge joint. My goal is to be able to move around the catapult sideways with wasd/arrow buttons as well as the rotation of the arm with the scroll wheel.

I've managed to get it to work by having the arm on kinematic, however this results in the base not being affected by gravity.

What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

You could be toggling " isKinematic" thru script only when you need it and toggle it back off when not needed.
there is a rigid body boolean property you can easly set up:

Rb.isKinematic = true;